# Dynamic Grouping and Sorting of Data Table

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a list collection of the below class with sample data such as [{col1,asc},{col2,desc},{col3,asc}] etc.. which can be dynamic. The GroupField matches the column names of a data table
(col1,col2,col3 are column names and asc/desc are the sort orders)

```
public class GroupContainer
{    
    public string GroupField { get; set; }    
    public string GroupSortOrder { get; set; }   
}
```

How can I use this collection to do a group by and sort on a data table dynamically(Something like the below)?

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(col1,col2,col3).OrderBy(col1,col2,col3)
```

Thanks,
Aravind

Comment: Ever used the dynamic linq library?

Comment: Sorry not yet, we are using System.Linq to perform necessary logic.